# Div that reveals another image

Tags: javascript, css

I need a div to reveal parts from another image (that is beneath it it in z-order).

in other words, when my div is at a certain position, only the part of the background image that is directly beneath the div should be visible (and everything else in the image should be hidden).

I made an animated gif to better illustrate the question:
http://whattaclick.com/illustrate.gif

EDIT: hmm.. the gif seems to start animating only in chrome, with firefox it wont work unless saved on the computer first.

Any ideas on what would be a good approach? I was first thinking of using css clip to hide the background image, but it's kind of a lot of work to keep manually inserting the clip values. It would be easier if I could somehow tell the browser to hide everything except the inside area of the div.

Comment: not related but very nice gif there. :D. worth the entire explanation. a picture worth thousand words. animated picture worth +1. :)

Comment: also, use of background-position might work. the scope that want to reveal the z-index might be a clone of the background that moves by background-position. just an idea. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it.

[Image Area Select](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply! Can this plugin use a div as the crop boundary or will I have to define the coordinates instead? If I need coordinates, then I'm not sure why the plugin would be better than just a css clip-property..

Comment: I am not sure. But in my comments link, Number 9, PanView seems to use div's. Myslef I use http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/

Comment: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/

Comment: I really apppreciate your input! I'm just not sure if this link that you posted can do what I need.. The thing is I need to hide parts of an image that are not part of the div that gives the dimensions for the hide. In other words, simply toggling the div on/off wont help me hide the corresponding area of the image in the background..